# Calling Routes from a js angular 1.5.8 file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I've my backend developed in Silex with various routes that I can fully access using localhost:8080/project/api/index.php/user (example of a route).

if i'm coding an http get(I use only one controller called mainController ) in a js file using angular 1.5.8, how can I make that when I enter angularsite/user

(user is the route, "/user"), it returns me the data and then show it on my index.html ?

Comment: Are you asking how to send a get request in angular?

Comment: how to receive a Get, I have /route1  that returns me some data.I want to retrieve the data in my js file where I'm developing angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your app routes to your mainController controller.

```
angular.module('YourProject', [
    'YourModule',
    'ngRoute'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/user', {
            templateUrl: 'view.html',
            controllerAs: 'mainCtrl',
            controller: 'mainController '
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/user'
        });
}])
```

Now when the page loads the RouteProvider will finds the default path to `user` (default route) route and that will load your view and controller. The templateUrl contains the route to the template.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to load a partial page you can do something like this..

```
'use strict';
 var App = angular.module('YourProject', ['ngRoute', 'AppControllers']);

App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/user', {
      templateUrl: 'user.html'
  }).
  otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/path'
  });
}]);
```

Since your question mentions an API if you are trying to just load some data you can call user API with something like this from your controller (provided that the url given is an API which accepts GET request and responds with JSON data)..

```
var AppControllers = angular.module('AppControllers', []);

AppControllers.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,  $http) {

    //Declare a function to fetch user data from API
    $scope.user= function () {
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: baseURL + 'project/api/index.php/user'
        }
        return $http(req).success(function (data,status,header) {
           $scope.user = data;
        }).error(function () {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

   //Call the get user function
    $scope.user();

}]);
```

And finally in your partial file (user.html) add the controller to bind it with the controller declared above.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="YourProject">
<body>
<head>
  <title>User Page</title>
</head>
<div class="user-content" ng-controller="MainController">
</body>
</html>
```